# How to apply HashMap in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I need to update some data  dynamically which are in array without appending new entry

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        isMounted: false
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isMounted: true })
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ isMounted: false })
}

updateData(msg) {
   if(this.state.isMounted){
    this.setState(
        update(this.state, { data: { $push: [msg] } }),   
    );
   }
}
```

// updateDate method will trigger dynamically